# Fix filter for tables

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, filtering

I'm having trouble trying to fix the filters I used for the tables in my website.
The thing is that I put a filter in each column of the table so the user can filter the category that is required.

Here I have 2 different problems:

1. when I use the filter for a column that has numbers (for example, if I want to filter all the boxes that has 20 centimetres long) it sometimes take that value from another column and shows it (for example, it alto shows those boxes that have 20 centimetres depth, but have a different length). Is there a way to avoid that and to make each filter only with the results of its column?
2. after filtering, when I want to change the value of the filter to look for other results, it does not bring any results. It seems like a bug, or something that does not work properly and I dont know how to fix.

This is my website where you can see the tables and see the errors im talking about: http://kickads.mobi/sipea/canastos_cajones.html

It also happens that when you want to see all the rows again, the filter is empty. 
No text is shown in the dropdown.

```js
function filterText(select) {
  var rex = new RegExp($(select).val());
  if (rex == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {

    $('.content:visible').filter(function() {
      return !rex.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('.filterText').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tabla">
  <tr>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
    <th>Medidas (mm)
      <select class='filterText' style='background- 
       color: #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; 
      display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
        <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
        <option value='1000x400x50'>1000x400x50</option>
        <option value='all'>Todos</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>Capacidad de carga (kg./m2)
      <select class='filterText' style='background-color: #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 
      5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
        <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
        <option value='500'>500</option>
        <option value='all'>Todos</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>Color
      <select class='filterText' style='background-color: 
       #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
        <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
        <option value='Blanco'>Blanco</option>
        <option value='Negro'>Negro</option>
        <option value='all'>Todos</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>Material
      <select class='filterText' style='background-color: 
       #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
        <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
        <option value='Virgen'>Virgen</option>
        <option value='Reciclado'>Reciclado</option>
        <option value='all'>Todos</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="content">
    <td>SP0125BL</td>

    <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>

    <td>1000x400x50</td>

    <td>500</td>

    <td>Blanco</td>

    <td>Virgen</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="content">
    <td>SP0125NE</td>

    <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>

    <td>1000x400x50</td>

    <td>500</td>

    <td>Negro</td>

    <td>Reciclado</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: select the column instead of reading text from the whole row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$('.content:visible').filter(function() {
```

you may act directly on columns:

```
var idx = $(select).closest('th').index() + 1; // get current column index....
$('.content:visible td:nth-child(' + idx + ')').filter(function() {
```

```js
function filterText(select)
{
    var rex = new RegExp($(select).val());
    if(rex =="/all/"){
        clearFilter();
    }else{
        var idx = $(select).closest('th').index() + 1;
        $('.content:visible td:nth-child(' + idx + ')').filter(function() {
            return !rex.test(this.textContent.trim());
        }).closest('tr').hide();
    }
}

function clearFilter() {
    $('.filterText').val('Filtro');
    $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="tabla">
    <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Descripción</th>
        <th>Medidas (mm) <select class='filterText' style='background-color: #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
            <option
                    value='1000x400x50'>1000x400x50
            </option>
            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
        </select></th>
        <th>Capacidad de carga (kg./m2) <select class='filterText' style='background-color: #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:
  5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
            <option value='500'>500</option>
            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
        </select></th>
        <th>Color <select class='filterText' style='background-color:
   #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
            <option value='Blanco'>Blanco</option>
            <option value='Negro'>Negro</option>
            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
        </select></th>
        <th>Material <select class='filterText' style='background-color:
   #d9232d; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; display:inline-block' style='display:inline-block' onchange='filterText(this)'>
            <option disabled selected>Filtro</option>
            <option value='Virgen'>Virgen</option>
            <option value='Reciclado'>Reciclado</option>
            <option value='all'>Todos</option>
        </select></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
        <td>SP0125BL</td>
        <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>
        <td>1000x400x50</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>Blanco</td>
        <td>Virgen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content">
        <td>SP0125NE</td>
        <td>Piso plástico relleno</td>
        <td>1000x400x50</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <td>Negro</td>
        <td>Reciclado</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But now I have trouble in one little thing: if you use the filter, and then select "all" to show all the results again, the filter square is empty, and it should say "filtro" so you can use it again. How can I solve that?